Why does this logging method not print to the console when the queue does not exist?
I am working with a method that is used within a larger script that is used to log information to a queue with a fallback to print the message to the console if the queue has not been created.
def _log(self, msg):
   
    if self.queue:
        self.queue.put(msg)
    else:
        print(msg)

However when I use the code in a separate script that I have made to test my understanding of its functionality I get an error.
import queue

class Thing:
    def __init__ (self, num1, num2):
        self.num1 = num1
        self.num2 = num2
     
    def _log(self, msg):
       
        if self.queue:
            self.queue.put(msg)
        else:
            print(msg)
    
    def add(self):
        self._log(self.num1 + self.num2)

test1 = Thing(1,2)
test1.add()

AttributeError: 'Thing' object has no attribute 'queue'

My understanding of this code is that if no queue has been initialized then the log should print to the console instead? Why is that not the case?

Have you looked at __init__ of the original class?

Nowhere in your code is the queue attribute added to Thing, hence the error.

The __init__ method should initialize self.queue = None so the if statement will work.

The expression self.queue requires the attribute to exist, even if its value is None. However, I would recommend initializing it with some object whose put method is equivalent to print, rather than making _log check for the special case.

self.queue does not exist.  How did you expect it to be created?

@JohnGordon OP seems to expect self.queue to evaluate to None if the attribute is undefined.

The error is explained pretty simply. Thing has no attribute "queue". The interpreter cannot find it and so breaks. If you used "try, except" then if the code within the try would normally break, then the except runs and if it works, the try bit runs. This is a good way to do what you want if I am understanding correctly. I have entered an example of this use below.
try:
    this will break
except:
    print("and yet this will still run")

I hope I understood your problem right and this helps.

Thanks for the response. I understand the queue is not initialized but as I read the code if there is not a queue then the function should print to the console instead?  If that is not what the else statement does then what is the point in it/ does it actually do anything?

The else condition will fire if self.queue exists but does not evaluate to True, which happens for None, 0, "", [ ], ... .
